# Where are the sync settings in iTunes 11 for Windows?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, windows

I've just upgraded to iTunes 11 on Win 7 Home Premium x64.

No matter how I try, I simply cannot find the synchronization setting for pictures/podscasts/music/movies etc.

Can someone *please* point me in the right directeion?

Comment: To what device do you need to sync content? To iCloud or Apple TV or an iOS device? Each of those items has a setup guide explaining how to set up sync in iTunes.

Answer (score 4):

I actually had to ask an Apple Genius (at the local Apple Store). Once a pod is "mounted", a little button appears to the left of the iTunes Store button. It says "iPod" and has a little graphic that you can use to "unmount" the pod. If you click the word "iPod" you get to the sync options display. If you click on the graphic, you unmount the pod. There is no indication that the word is clickable, the word and the graphic are on a single button. Lousy UI (at least in that respect) if you ask me. –

Answer (score 1):

From dropdown menu: File, Devices, Sync

Comment: File > Devices > Sync simply synchronizes the Pod to iTunes.  It does *not* allow you to set sync options like which directory to get pictures from or which playlists to load or which podcast...